# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

We have an iPad app built with flutter and using firebase storage running in production. We got an unusual error where some iPads but not all just crash on file upload to firebase storage. The error says `Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException` in Crashlytics.
I have read some articles with similar issues and most of the time it is due to memory leak but I do not understand why only some iPads get this exception but not all although they have the same configuration and the same chip.

Has anyone ever faced the same issue ?

We tried doing the same exact manipulations on 2 identical iPads and only one is not able to upload a file to firebase storage.

Here is the trace :

`Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException 0  CoreFoundation                 0x9c44 (Manquant UUID df935525036c30ae8d1d4e5f3dd7876a) 1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x17e5c (Manquant UUID 1ff34faad6c3319bb651854379e9eadf) 2  Foundation                     0x4e150c (Manquant UUID 08587e68599130bba36237b31c21007e) 3  Flutter                        0x1ba6c (Manquant UUID 4c4c449c55553144a1909abb36b88cdf) 4  Flutter                        0x5d5b24 (Manquant UUID 4c4c449c55553144a1909abb36b88cdf) 5  Runner                         0x459510 __100-[FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin startFIRStorageObservableTaskForArguments:andFLTFirebaseStorageTaskType:]_block_invoke_2.149 + 608 (FLTFirebaseStoragePlugin.m:608) 6  libdispatch.dylib              0x2320 (Manquant UUID 5c90fe9b7b3735e19e3e3baf6fda9ab0) 7  libdispatch.dylib              0x3eac (Manquant UUID 5c90fe9b7b3735e19e3e3baf6fda9ab0) 8  libdispatch.dylib              0xb534 (Manquant UUID 5c90fe9b7b3735e19e3e3baf6fda9ab0) 9  libdispatch.dylib              0xc0a4 (Manquant UUID 5c90fe9b7b3735e19e3e3baf6fda9ab0) 10 libdispatch.dylib              0x16cdc (Manquant UUID 5c90fe9b7b3735e19e3e3baf6fda9ab0) 11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xddc (Manquant UUID 41a466671d073fc097150f5990b8757f) 12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb7c (Manquant UUID 41a466671d073fc097150f5990b8757f)`